# Determine class of an object from id<protocol>

Tags: objective-c, class, syntax, casting, protocols

I have a class like so:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject <FooDataProvider>
...
@end
```

and somewhere along the line in another class I have a method with the interface:

```
-(void) doStuff:(id<FooDataProvider>)fooProvider{
...
}
```

And yet somwhere else I have

```
-(void) passMeClasses:(Class)theClass
{
<do stuff based on the class>
}
```

Usually I pass things to this method simply like

```
Foo* f = [[Foo alloc] init];
...
[bar passMeClasses:[f class]];
```

But Im not sure how to pass things I only have the id.. like so

```
id<FooDataProvider> f = [[Foo alloc] init];
....
[bar passMeClasses:[f ?????]];
```

or alternatively how to do it from the doStuff method

```
-(void) doStuff:(id<FooDataProvider>)fooProvider{
  Class c = [fooProvider howDoIGetMyClass];
  bar passMeClasses:c];
}
```

Can someone help me in determining the class from the id?

Sorry for the long winded explanation, but hopefully its clear!

Comment: Update your question with the declaration of `FooDataProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

`[f class]`

`class` is a method. It's called on the object. The object will return its class (or it should; it can technically return something else and sometimes does). The type of the variable is completely irrelevant at runtime. At runtime *all* object pointers are `id`. That's why [method signature type encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100-SW1) only designate "an object goes here." (See `@`.) They can't express the specific type of the object.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but that seems to go against what I am seeing.  Simply calling [f class] gives the error "no known instance method for selector 'class'".  I am able to first cast it to a id, and then do it such as: [(id)f class]

Comment: @xceph Make sure that your `FooDataProvider` protocol extends the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: @rmaddy Thats the problem, thanks!  If you want to add it as a true reply so that I can accept it please do so.